# Firebase querying - I get some type of NSArray as result (only sometimes)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I've got a firebase database like this:

```
userIndexes
-- 1: uid1
-- 2: uid2
-- 3: uid3
```

I want to get the uid by using the key. So I'll query it like this:

```
DataService.sharedInstance.DB_REF_USERS_INDEXED_BY_ID.queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: "2").queryLimited(toFirst: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
     print(snapshot.value)
})
```

When I use `2` or `3` as starting point, I get this print (here it's `2`):

> Optional({ 
>       2 = uid2; })

I easily can cast this to `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`

But when I use `1` as starting point, I get this:

> optional(<__NSArrayM 0x6000000494b0>( < null >,
>   uid1 ) )
>   If I try to cast this to a Dictionary, it just gets `nil`

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked same question in [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/vTvuo4QmWR0) ..

> You should avoid arrays (specifically, numeric, sequential ids) in distributed systems.

**For more on how array-like behaviors are handled in Firebase and Why you should avoid arrays:**

It clearly defines in old firebase doc., whats going on when you use Arrays in firebase. check [Arrays in firebase Database](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase)

You can also go through [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)  .. where it says

> if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array.

Comment: Ah, I think I understood it. The thing is, I don't treat them as array keys in that matter. For example, it could look like this: `--1: uid1 --45: uid45` Every user has it's own key and can be added or removed there. So I might solve this issue by renaming the keys to something like `key45`, right?

Comment: yes right ... always use some string as key rather than Int because sequential manner key often converted in to arrays as firebase belives that its autoincremented ...