# Firebase Swift Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10591cc30) to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am using Swift with Firebase as my backend. For some reason, I am getting this error in one of my snapshots:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10591cc30) to 'NSDictionary'
```

I get this when I use this code:

```
let snapVal = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Why is this happening to just this data snapshot, when it looks like all the other data snapshots?

The data looks like this:

```
Snap (PERSON) {
    1 =     {
        DESCRIPTION = "Brief description here..";
        "DOB" = "10/15/92, 8:29 PM";
        "STATUS" = 1;
        SONG = "A song";
        "START_DATE" = "10/05/16, 7:59 PM";
    };
}
```

The snapVal looks like this (when I do not specify it as [String: AnyObject]:

```
(
    "<null>",
        DESCRIPTION = "Brief description here..";
        "DOB" = "10/15/92, 8:29 PM";
        "STATUS" = 1;
        SONG = "A song";
        "START_DATE" = "10/05/16, 7:59 PM";
    }
)
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Because `snapshot.value` is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: @Ryan check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39122662/4601170

Comment: @Ryan update your question with your retrieval function.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that the data that you are retrieving is of type **NSDictionary**

Then Try changing :-

```
 let snapVal = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
```

To :-

```
 if let snapVal = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

        print(snapVal)

      }
```

Comment: I tried that, and it should work but it is never executed because snapshot.value cannot be of type [String: AnyObject]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by changing the child value from 0, 1, 2 etc to string values such as p0, p1 which solved my problem. Firebase doesn't actually save a title value for that child when you only use Int's. If that makes sense.

So change the 1 to something like "value1" or "v1" and use swift to reorganise the array with `array.sort { $1.status > $0.status }`

```
Snap (PERSON) {
    1 =     {
        DESCRIPTION = "Brief description here..";
        "DOB" = "10/15/92, 8:29 PM";
        "STATUS" = 1;
        SONG = "A song";
        "START_DATE" = "10/05/16, 7:59 PM";
    };
}
```

**to:**

```
Snap (PERSON) {
    "value1" =     {
        DESCRIPTION = "Brief description here..";
        "DOB" = "10/15/92, 8:29 PM";
        "STATUS" = 1;
        SONG = "A song";
        "START_DATE" = "10/05/16, 7:59 PM";
    };
}
```