# Retrieve Int in Firebase Database with Swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I have this code:**

```
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        print(snapshot)

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [Int : Bool] {
            print(dict)
        }
    })
```

**That prints this snapshot:**

```
Snap (availability) {
    1 = 1;
    2 = 1;
    3 = 1;
    4 = 1;
    5 = 1;
    6 = 0;
    7 = 0;
}
```

My issue is that my `Dictionnary` `dict` is not initialized because of the `Int` values 1,2,...,6,7; Firebase might don't give them as `Int`. I also tried to retrieve these values with the `dict` as `[String : Bool]`. Not working too. Same issue with `[NSNumber : Bool]`

**My question:** How can I retrieve these values considering their child names are Ints?

Comment: Likely they are instances of `NSNumber`

Comment: BTW: Both Your example and the alternative example contains `[String : Bool]`.

Comment: Oh sorry thanks mate! And BTW, `NSNumber` doesn't work!

Comment: Why not just [String : Int]

Comment: @Pieter Laebens Because it doesn't work! ;)

Comment: What your DB looks like?

Comment: @i6x86 It looks like the snapshot I pasted. The matter doesn't come from the DB. Because if I put strings instead of the ints 1,2...,6,7: this works. The issue is that Firebase don't send me this values as `Int` and that's why my condition is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use Ints in a sequential way Firebase treats them like arrays. 
You should avoid using Ints like keys, because:

> if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array.

Here you [more details about the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122662/5843195)!
And some [best practices](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) from the Firebase blog.

Comment: Thanks mate I will avoid that. ;)

Comment: But is it possible as value?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: if you mean if it is possible to retrieve the Ints lf they were values, yes it is, always when your keys are Strings.