# Firebase is crashing sometimes, but not always

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I am retrieving an array, I am using this function:

```
self.gameRef!.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let seeds = value?["seed"] as! [Int]
}
```

This is my error:

[image]

This is my structure:

[image]

However, most of the time it is working. Sometimes, I get this crash. I have no idea why. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The reason you are getting the crash most possibly is because you are force unwrapping to [Int] instead of optional unwrapping. Now as far as why your array is not an Int array some times, is a different question that needs more info as to why it is not recognized.

Comment: Yea, it is strange... The seed is always available before querying it.

Comment: Have you tried printing out `value` when it crashes to see what it contains? You can turn on your exception breakpoints and when it pauses on that line right before a crash maybe print out `value` and see what it contains at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to unwrap snapshot value

```
self.gameRef!.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

             if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:[Int]], let seeds = value["seed"]{
             //continue
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use Ints in a sequential way Firebase treats them like arrays. And you are casting this like a Dictionary. You should avoid using Ints like keys, because:

> if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys
>   between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values,
>   then Firebase will render it as an array

You might want to take a look at [this answer too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122662)