# Firebase not receiving key values Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason i cannot receive the values of my child and im not understanding why. Each value is represented as a double.

Does not make it past

```
if let snapDict = snap.value as? [Double:AnyObject]{
```

[image]

```
func recieveChartValues() {

    //Firebase Initialization
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("general_room_index").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in


        if let snapDict = snap.value as? [Double:AnyObject]{


            for each in snapDict{

                print("key ", each.key)
                self.values.append(each.key)
            }
        }
    })

}//retrive values func
```

Comment: what's the issue? your snap has value or not?

Comment: no value. my snap is not printing a value at all.

Comment: never makes it past if let snapDict = snap.value as? [Double:AnyObject]{

Comment: try checking if snap.exists() this will check if snap has any data or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array.

So I believe that you always use some string as key rather than Int because sequential manner key often converted in to arrays as firebase believes that its auto incremented ...

More info. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122662/4601170)

Comment: ok before this if let, `print(snap.value)`  .. and tell me result of it

Comment: it gives me all the values 1114,
1114,
1114,
1114
)
)

Comment: can you show me append my current code into a double array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138696/discussion-between-ei-captain-v2-0-and-codechicksrock).